# Убрать дублирование $_GET параметров при редиректе

Tags: javascript, php, get, редирект

Убрать дублирование `$_GET` параметров при редиректе

на сайте делаю редирект с учтением `$_GET` параметров, но после редиректра эти параметры в строке почему-то дублируются, никак не могу понять почему
вот код
сначала получаю все параметры и формирую адреса для телефона и планшета

```
<?php
$url="?";
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) 
  { 
    $url=$url."$key=$value&"; 
  } 

  $url=substr($url, 0, -1);
  $url1="http://copy-lend.ru/phone/index.php".$url;
  $url2="http://copy-lend.ru/tablet/index.php".$url;
  //echo $url;
?>
```

дальше в коде делаю редирект через скрипт

```
(function(a, b, c) {
  var d = function() {
      if (navigator.maxTouchPoints > 1) return !0;
      if (window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia("(-moz-touch-enabled)").matches) return !0;
      for (var a = ["Webkit", "Moz", "O", "ms", "Khtml"], b = 0, c = a.length; b < c; b++) {
        var f = a[b] + "MaxTouchPoints";
        if (f in navigator && navigator[f]) return !0
      }
      try {
        return document.createEvent("TouchEvent"), !0
      } catch (d) {}
      return !1
    }(),
    g = function(a) {
      a += "=";
      for (var b = document.cookie.split(";"), c = 0; c < b.length; c++) {
        for (var f = b[c]; f.charAt(0) == " ";) f = f.substring(1, f.length);
        if (f.indexOf(a) ==
          0) return f.substring(a.length, f.length)
      }
      return null
    };
  if (g("inbrowserediting") != "true") {
    var f, g = g("devicelock");
    g == "phone" && c ? f = c : g == "tablet" && b && (f = b);
    if (g != a && !f)
      if (window.matchMedia) window.matchMedia("(max-device-width: 415px)").matches && c ? f = c : window.matchMedia("(max-device-width: 960px)").matches && b && d && (f = b);
      else {
        var a = Math.min(screen.width, screen.height) / (window.devicePixelRatio || 1),
          g = window.screen.systemXDPI || 0,
          i = window.screen.systemYDPI || 0,
          g = g > 0 && i > 0 ? Math.min(screen.width / g, screen.height / i) :
          0;
        (a <= 370 || g != 0 && g <= 3) && c ? f = c : a <= 960 && b && d && (f = b)
      }
    if (f) document.location = f + (document.location.search || "") + (document.location.hash || ""), document.write('<style type="text/css">body {visibility:hidden}</style>')
  }
})("desktop", "<?php echo $url2;?>", "<?php echo $url1;?>");
```

в результате при переходе на сайт по такой ссылке 
http://copy-lend.ru/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=AdwordsPoiskMoskva&id=category1

если экран меньше 415 пикселей, то идет перенапрвление на мобильную версию, и в итоге строка получается вот такой

http://copy-lend.ru/phone/index.php?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=AdwordsPoiskMoskva&id=category1?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=AdwordsPoiskMoskva&id=category1

хотя в коде страницы  выводит вот так http://copy-lend.ru/phone/index.php?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=AdwordsPoiskMoskva&id=category1

в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: На php параметры удобно собирать функцией http_build_query. Проблема видимо в том что в js скрипте добавляются те же параметры `if(f)document.location=f+(document.location.search||"")`

Comment: Спасибо! так и думал что дублирование из за js